# undefined is not an object (evaluating 'ToolbarAndroid.propTypes') react-native-general-calendars

Tags: react-native

This error is shown when I upgrade react-native version to 0.61.1

I tried to install Proptypes library

```
<Calendar
            onTouchPrev={this.onTouchPrev}
            onTitlePress={this.onTitlePress}
            minDate={_today}
            markedDates={this.state._markedDates}
            theme={{
              backgroundColor: "#ffffff",
              calendarBackground: "#ffffff",
              textSectionTitleColor: "#b6c1cd",
              selectedDayBackgroundColor: "#00adf5",
              selectedDayTextColor: "#ffffff",
              todayTextColor: "#00adf5",
              dayTextColor: "#2d4150",
              textDisabledColor: "#d9e1e8",
              dotColor: "#00adf5",
              selectedDotColor: "#ffffff",
              arrowColor: "#00adf5",
              monthTextColor: "#00adf5",
              indicatorColor: "blue",
              textDayFontWeight: "300",
              textMonthFontWeight: "bold",
              textDayHeaderFontWeight: "300",
              textDayFontSize: 16,
              textMonthFontSize: 16,
              textDayHeaderFontSize: 16
            }}
            style={{ width: "98%", marginTop: 30 }}
            {...this.props}
            onDayPress={(
              date = { day, month, year, timestamp, dateString }
            ) => [this.onDateChange(date, startDate)]}
          />
```

And it produces this error message :

> undefined is not an object (evaluating 'ToolbarAndroid.propTypes')

Answer (score 1, accepted):

React Native has removed `ToolbarAndroid` from `v61` (maybe even `v60`, if i recall correctly from early attempts at integrating it in this version) onwards as part of the lean core effort. But, as of today, the documentation is [still available on the main site](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/toolbarandroid) . I guess this will be removed soon. See  this [Github issue](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/26591#issue-498739829)

There isn't (yet, maybe) a `@react-native-community` version as well. So possibly you may need to roll out your own or go with a `JS` variant